Write pyspark dataframe as a table in synapse dedicated pool
I have synpase dedicated pool. I connected to my synapse DWH and fetched tables data in a pyspark df - did some transformations and created new dataframes - when i am trying to load these pyspark dataframes back into synapse as new tables it gives me following error:
Error creating table: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
Tried this:
import pyodbc

# Define a function to check if the table exists
def table_exists(table_name):
    query = f"SELECT TABLE_NAME AS table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{table_name}'"
    try:
        result = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=f"({query}) as temp", properties=connection_properties).collect()
        return len(result) > 0
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error checking if table exists: {e}")
        return False

# Define a function to create the table if it doesn't exist
def create_table(table_name):
    create_table_sql = f"""
    CREATE TABLE dbo.{table_name} WITH (
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
    ) AS(
        SurrogateKey BIGINT,
        TenantID NVARCHAR(100),
        pkBookingID INT,
        fkUserID INT,
        fkLocationID INT,
        dateAdded DATETIME,
        trackDate DATETIME,
        fkHostID INT,
        noShow BIT,
        BookingSource INT,
        deleteBooking INT,
        RealStartDateTimeUTC DATETIME,
        RealEndDateTimeUTC DATETIME,
        bookingRealStartTime NVARCHAR(100),
        bookingRealEndTime NVARCHAR(100),
        cleanDownPeriod INT,
        cleanDownUnit INT,
        PipelineExecutionDate NVARCHAR(100)
    )
    """
    try:
        with pyodbc.connect(jdbc_url) as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(create_table_sql)
                conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error creating table: {e}")

# Table name
table_name = "tblBooking_DIM_archive"

# Check if the table exists and handle the DataFrame write operation
if table_exists(table_name):
    # Append the DataFrame to the existing table
    tblBooking_DIM_archive.write.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=table_name, mode="append", properties=connection_properties)
else:
    # Create a new table with the same schema and insert the DataFrame
    create_table(table_name)
    tblBooking_DIM_archive.write.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=table_name, mode="overwrite", properties=connection_properties)





----------
my connection parameters are fine..dont know why I am getting this error


To write data to a dedicated SQL pool within the same Synapse workspace as your notebook, you can use the synapsesql method.
I have tried an example in Scala, using parameters in Synapse notebooks:
Read the table from the dedicated sql pool:
%%spark
import com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.utils.Constants
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val pDatabaseName = "ddpool"
val pSchemaName = "dbo"
val pTableName = "Employee"
val df = spark.read.synapsesql(s"${pDatabaseName}.${pSchemaName}.${pTableName}")

Loading table data into dataframe:
%%spark
val df = spark.read.synapsesql(s"${pDatabaseName}.${pSchemaName}.${pTableName}")
df.show()

Transformation:
%%spark
val dfWithRenamedColumn = df.withColumnRenamed("HireDate", "Hire_Date")

Writing the dataframe to a new table in dedicated Sql Pool:
%%spark
import com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.utils.Constants
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val pDatabaseName = "ddpool"
val pSchemaName = "dbo"
val pTableName = "new_employee"
dfWithRenamedColumn.write.synapsesql(s"${pDatabaseName}.${pSchemaName}.${pTableName}")

Results:

In the example above, the items in curly brackets with a dollar sign (e.g., ${pDatabaseName}) are parameters.
You can set up a parameter cell in your notebook so these parameters can be passed in externally, such as from Azure Data Factory (ADF) or Synapse Pipelines using the Execute Notebook activity.
These parameters can then be reused throughout the notebook. You can learn more about Synapse Notebook parameters to see how this works.
